# Determine if there are only a defined set of characters in a String

Tags: java, regex

I've got an amount in a String in which I want to check if there is anything else present than figures, dots, and commas. So if anything else than `[0123456789,.]` is present, it should return false.

I currently check like this:

```
if ("495.6A,B76".matches(".*[0123456789].*")) {
```

This returns true, because the characters are indeed in the string. I just want to check if the string consists of ONLY these characters?

Comment: Just remove your .* and . at the end, so its "[01234567890,.]*" for your regex.

Answer (score 4):

You can just match for known symbols:

```
^[\\d,.]+$
```

**Visual Representation:**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

- [**Recommended Regex Reference**](http://regular-expressions.info)

**PS:** Note that if you're using `String#matches` then anchors `^ and $` (line start and line end) aren't really needed since those are implicit.

Therefore:

```
"495.6A,B76".matches("^[\\d,.]+$");
```

is same as:

```
"495.6A,B76".matches("[\\d,.]+");
```

and **both will return false.**

Comment: How do you generate this automaton image?

Comment: @kocko debuggex.com... Why it's given in lieu of an explanation, I have no idea.  Why it's getting upvoted simply for picture, also no idea.

Comment: @kocko: That I generated on http://debuggex.com SteveP: Anything wrong with my answer?

Comment: Yeah, you have almost 100K reputation, I expect a higher quality answer.  One with an explanation, at the very least...I understand that it's simple, but obviously OP is a regex novice.

Comment: Explanation was there in first line it self. OP already knows how to use character class. Besides I added a good regex reference and picture for explanation.

Comment: @anubhava He obviously doesn't know what `^` and `$` do, otherwise, he wouldn't have had to ask the question.  If you edit, I can remove my downvote...

Comment: Oh I didn't you have downvoted :) In any-case `^ and $` aren't needed for `String#matches` and I will edit the answer for that note.

Answer (score 3):

```
String regex = "^[0-9,.]+$"
```

`^` says "begins with"
`+` says 1 or more of the preceding (use `*` if empty string should match)
`$` says "ends with"
`[0-9]` == `[0123456789]`; additionally,  `[0-9]` == `[\\d]`.

Since everyone loves pictures, here you go:
[image: Regular expression visualization]

**EDIT:**
Didn't see that you were using `.matches()`, this automatically matches the entire string, so you can remove the `^` and `$` anchors.

Answer (score 1):

You can include specific characters to match using a character class `[]`

```
^[0-9,.]+$
```

Regular expression:

```
^              the beginning of the string
 [0-9,.]+      any character of: '0' to '9', ',', '.' (1 or more times)
$              before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (param.matches ("[0-9.]+"))  
System.out.println ("matches" );    
else      
System.out.println ("doesn't match");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the negation operator if you have a small set of defined characters, like so:

`[^\d,\.,]`

This will match any non-digit characters.

The alternative is to see if the entire string is just digits you want:

`^[\d\.,]$`

What you probably want is something more specific, which is a currency form (two decimals), like so:

`\d+\.\d\d`